Can Victorian engineers build spacecraft with an Epstein drive?
During the 18th century, astronomers discovered a variable star whose variability turned out to be a coded message, describing a simple way to build a rocket engine that (somehow) has performance similar to that of the Expanse's Epstein drive. By the Victorian age, this engine and its fuel can be easily produced.
However, Victorian materials and engineering precision didn't come close to what modern technology (or even early space-age technology) can achieve. My question is: given the existence of such a rocket engine, could otherwise realistic Victorian-era technology create interplanetary spacecraft?

Some details on the engine's performance:

Specific Impulse: 1,100,000 seconds
Max thrust: 1 MN
Open cycle cooling (drive heat is carried away by the exhaust plume)


Plot twist: they build the engine as instructed, then they all die 10 minutes after the takeoff after passing through Van Allen belt, because they did not discover what radiation means yet.

@void_ptr  I would think the radiation from the rocket engine would be far more powerful than that from the Van Allen belt.  A video from Curious Droid on the Van Allen belts and the risk they pose to astronauts:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNiscigIgBc

Option 1: The coded message includes all the instructions necessary to build the engine, including factory specs, advancing the Victorian Age to the 2050s overnight. Option 2: The K5 society that can cause a variable star to pulse in an intelligent way is stupid enough to not include full instructions, Queen Victoria's plans for galactic conquest fail. Option 3: The aliens weren't that stupid after all and Victoria England isn't who the message was intended for. (*Continued*)

... My point? If Victorian England can understand the instructions, they have the necessary background to build the factories that can build the engine. If they don't have the ability to build the factories, then they couldn't have understood the instructions in the first place. From the perspective of an electrical engineer, there's no possible way for Victorian England could understand the instructions. Even if they could, unless you're invoking magic, the simple telegraphic message (Morse Code...) would take a century to transmit. Don't explain any of this, just write a good story.

Why Victorian English? Maybe some other nation would make for a more interesting story. When Japanese artisans were first exposed to the Jacquard loom they already had been doing automation for centuries. Instead of treating the Jacquard as "white man's magic" they had the skills to quickly improve it.

dude HOW WOULD THEY GET THE INSTRUCTIONS ??  Write them down?  Really really quickly? The message could only be sent in a morse code like stye.  there was absolutely nothing like "a video camera, and VHS deck" that could RECORD such an incoming message

" HOW WOULD THEY GET THE INSTRUCTIONS ?? Write them down? "  Motion picture cameras could be used to record the variation of brightness in celestial objects.  Early examples of this existed in 1845, and if we assume people noticed that the stars were blinking in ways that could convey information then the technology may have developed more quickly than we saw in our own history.  It would certainly take a lot of work to decode but, again, put a bunch of people into decoding the information and answers might develop quickly.  Maybe publish codes in newspapers as puzzles for the public to solve.

1.1 million seconds means an exhaust velocity of 10800 km/s, 3.6% c. Producing 1 MN of thrust at that specific impulse will mean a power output just in terms of the exhaust plume's kinetic energy of 5.4 terawatts.
Firstly, justifying a vehicle built with Victorian technology with such a drive not converting itself to glowing vapor and wreckage just due to proximity to its own exhaust plume is going to be a stretch.
Secondly, the ability to produce such an engine and some fuel to run it implies a huge variety of other capabilities that they will be much more ready to take advantage of. For example, they could use the same technology, greatly scaled down, to boil steam for steam engines without needing coal. Or, they could easily weaponize it.
Finally, this is an enormous amount of power output. Some quick number crunching suggests it'd be achievable with a very high efficiency fusion engine, but it stretches credibility for Victorian technology to be capable of creating a fusion system that not only works, but is close to the physical limits of performance. It's almost more believable if they got instructions for building some matter-annihilation engine using principles we don't even understand now.
The matter annihilation approach would also work around the exotic fuel problem of fusion power, and allow for future improvements that give even more output.

The drive was some species of fusion drive using Epstein's innovative "magnetic coil exhaust" - You could get around problems with materials by having the fusion happen far from (and directed away from) the hardware.

The Epstein drive is actually a really bad example, because of the word you left off: it uses "magnetic coil exhaust acceleration", to improve performance (and exhaust velocity) many times over. This would mean a electromagnetic acceleration system with power consumption dwarfing the actual fusion rocket, and the hardware itself has to carry all that power (and it has to be generated somewhere). But even ignoring that, Victorian industry was not up to building giant magnetic nozzles and external magnetic fusion confinement fields containing and directing terawatts of nuclear fusion.

Even assuming they could build the design as given (Which they possibly could have, just at utterly hideous expense, depending on what rare elements are needed and how complete the instructions are) how are they going to get it into orbit? It's putting out the same energy as the Hiroshima bomb every 16 seconds, and doing it as a rather high speed and temperature jet of plasma. I definitely wouldn't recommend lighting it off in the atmosphere.  So unless it can be rather deeply throttled they're going to need other things they probably don't have before they can make use of it properly.

@Perkins yeah, even if they could build a ship that could survive running the drive in space, launch and landing would be incredibly violent. Perhaps a very small scale version could be a heat source for an air breathing engine for liftoff and landing, but the added complexity makes it less and less believable that they could actually build and operate such a vehicle. Honestly, it'd be more believable to come up with some antigravity drive, as in The Road Not Taken by Turtledove.

@ChristopherJamesHuff I don't expect a ship to withstand running the drive would be all that difficult for them. Since the plans are just for the drive and don't include the "acceleration drugs" the show uses to handwave the bit where the crew turns into a millimeter-thick layer of paste on the rear bulkhead they're kind of limited to at most two or three g, and even their steel will be good enough if they just use enough of it. Might even have the handy side-effect of providing enough shielding for the crew that the radiation wouldn't fry them.

@Perkins the problem isn't withstanding the acceleration or shielding the crew, the problem is that the radiation would likely melt the ship. Again, terawatts of power output. If they absorb 0.1% of that, they have gigawatts of waste heat to dispose of.

@ChristopherJamesHuff Presumably the drive itself has some way of disposing of that heat though, or else it would have a very similar problem.  So, if nothing else, you just make sure the entire ship is in the shadow of the drive unit.  If that's not enough, then you just bring along a sufficiently large mass of total-loss coolant.  This ship is going to be absurdly expensive enough with all the rare elements they need to learn to extract anyway that nobody will mind.

In terms of engineering maybe, in terms of materials no. The Victorians had the precision engineering to build a rocket engine with tight enough engineering tolerances to theoretically perform, after a fashion, (probably not tight enough for such a high performance unit though). What they didn't have was the material science to control the alloy quality of components to the point where they would perform as designed. Without this there would be extremely high component failure rates such that the engine will explode, repeatedly, in short order.
However:
All of that is pretty moot, the Victorians are several paradigm shifts away from being able to understand the object they're trying to build. If they were to build it anyway, it is possible to build complex objects that you don't understand, you'd have issues justifying the initial data transfer. You'd have to start with the extraction and refinement of elements like Titanium, Indium, Rhenium (which no-one had even isolated), Molybdenum, Ruthenium, Niobium, Tungsten etc... in industrial quantities and work from there. To give the Victorians enough information would take years, probably decades, they simply don't have the information reception technology to absorb the plans fast enough to get the project off the ground.

Honestly, limited material science is the biggest reason we can not make such an engine today.  At today's level of technology, we could design a fusion rocket just fine, but the kinds of electromagnets, cryogenics, and superconductors we'd need to make it happen simply can't be made with our known industrial processes.

@Nosajimiki I expect we could probably build one too.  Especially if you were content with a refinement on Project Orion type technology rather than some of the speculative components of the Epstein drive.  The thing our current materials science wouldn't let us do is build a small one.  And the expense to build a large one in orbit would need a pretty big payoff to justify.

On the latter point: consider the problems we're having developing EVA suits usable on the moon, even with modern CAD, materials, and automated manufacturing. Even if you handed Victorian-era Earth a bunch of pre-built drives, they're far from actually being able to make productive use of them.

On its own, a rocket just goes. It doesn't go in a straight line, and it particularly doesn't go on the line you want it to go on. In order to control it, you need a control system that does three things: determines where it is, determines where it wants to go, and positions the rocket nozzle(s) accordingly. (It's also possible to use thrust vectoring - steering by throttling back one of your several rocket engines. Assuming you have several rocket engines. But since this is more complex in pretty much every way, it's probably not going to save you.)
None of these steps are going to be easy, or really even feasible, with Victorian technology.
Step 1 is slightly plausible, in that the fundamental tool used to determine the rocket's orientation - the gyrocompass - was invented in the Victorian era. (The tail end of it, but never mind that.) However, these were relatively large compasses designed to be used aboard ships; they were not hardened to survive the rigors of rocket launch. (In terms of acceleration and vibration, I'm not sure the Victorian era had anything comparable to the rigors of spaceflight, outside of the most powerful of natural disasters.) They were also prohibitively large and heavy for missile work. But they did exist.
Step 2 is less plausible. Once the rocket's orientation is determined, you need to compare it to the desired orientation (which changes during ascent) and then translate the difference into precise commands for each of the thruster actuators. And you have no electronics with which to do the job.
Mechanical computers did exist for solving somewhat similar (though less complex) problems in artillery. In the 1910s, there were computers that, given the range and orientation to another ship, could translate them into approximate firing solutions for the ship's guns. (But they couldn't score hits on computed solutions alone until the development of electronics and radar; considerable manual work was needed "correcting" shots.) Your mechanical computer would need to be much more precise than this, because a human trying to correct it by hand will invariably overcorrect and you will not go to space today.
It goes without saying that like the gyrocompasses, early naval firing computers weren't up to the rigor of space travel (they weren't always up to the rigors of ocean travel, in practice) and were much too large and heavy to fit on a practical rocket. So, you'd need to be much more advanced than the state of the art in multiple ways.
That gets you to step 3. Hydraulic controls are available, but will they be durable enough and accurate enough for the purpose? A few millimeters left and right can spell the difference between getting to space and getting the Range Safety Officer to press the big red button. (Oh, you don't have radar-detonated explosives? Hope you don't land anywhere important...)
Having a rocket engine, although not trivial in itself, is a far cry from having a rocket.

+1 for Up-Goer Five's "You will not go to space today"

Well stated.  We had at least the basic idea of a rocket for centuries before going to space.  Building a rocket powerful enough to get to space was likely possible given the knowledge of materials and the scale of manufacturing of the Victorian Era.  The necessary navigation technology may have existed.  What would be difficult is the control systems that could integrate the navigation with the controls to act with the speed and precision necessary.  Maybe if people worked on this long and hard enough they could figure it out but by then the Victorian Era may be over and its all obsolete.

nit: I believe the steering system you dismiss in the first paragraph is called differential thrust or differential throttling, not thrust vectoring.

Actually, the first described option ("... and positions the rocket nozzle(s) accordingly") is a thrust vectoring.

Do note that having a rocket as powerful as an "Epstein Drive" would give you a heck of a lot of leeway on the size and weight of the guidance systems, etc.  And also would reduce the precision of flightpath required. A lot of the launch precision requirements are due to having just barely enough thrust and fuel to get there.  Being able to have a nice, large safety margin on engine power and fuel reserves makes it more like flying an airplane.

People have been able to produce precision machines for some time before the Victorian Era, and had also produced many of the materials that would be needed to build a practical spacecraft.  In my estimation there were two things holding people back from going to space at the time.
First is without access to the transistor it was difficult to produce practical devices for computation and communications.  There were "computers" at the time but they'd be people trained in mathematics to where they could do calculations quickly, though perhaps without precision in order to do get output quickly.  There were mechanical calculators that could aid in getting calculations done quickly but they were not exactly small and light.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmometer
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide-predicting_machine
To land on the moon it took a lot of calculations to time the rockets just right for a soft landing.  Part of this landing required getting an accurate distance from the moon's surface which was done by radar, and transistors were vital to getting radar to work.  Some calculations had to be given to ground control since the computers on the Apollo craft would not be powerful enough to do this on their own in the time they'd be needed.
Second is without an understanding of the atom there was no power source that would be small enough to take people to space.  The Apollo spacecraft didn't have a nuclear reactor but they did have radio-thermal generators that were built from materials produced in a nuclear reactor.  The power density of these devices was relatively low but the energy density was high, meaning they produced a lot of energy but did so slowly.
If people were given an accurate model of the atom, and therefore an understanding of nuclear fusion and fission, then perhaps with Victorian Era manufacturing techniques people could produce nuclear rocket engines.  Making something large enough and precise enough that it could launch itself into space may have been merely a matter of getting enough people motivated to produce it.
Much of what was needed to get people to the moon and back existed for centuries.  New materials like artificial polymers certainly helped but there's been natural polymers known for some time, such as rubber.  If people were given knowledge of nuclear fission and fusion in the Victorian Era then they may have been able to produce a fusion drive.  What would remain a problem, in my opinion, would be the means to communicate without wires and the means to perform precise calculations quickly enough to navigate between planets while avoiding collisions.
Maybe the calculation problem could be solved with mechanical computers.  We've seen some very elaborate computation devices built in the past, some dating back to the 2nd century BC. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism
Maybe instead of radar a means of measuring distance optically could be developed.  Maybe optical communications capable of covering interplanetary distance could be developed too.  Radiotelegraph communications existed after the close of the Victorian Era but if there's been a leap in technology from getting plans for a fusion propulsion rocket then moving up the development of radio and radar by a few decades would not be out of the question.  With the means to produce electronics for a radio then it's a small step for analog electronic computers as a lightweight alternative to mechanical computers.
This is an interesting question and I've asked myself similar questions before.  Physics didn't change so nothing really kept people from developing so many of the technologies we enjoy today at some earlier time.  What was often the limiting factor was finding enough people interested in developing a technology.  What often drives interest into a technology would be a hardship like war or disease.  Once there's something that threatens life then people will set aside resources to get a solution quickly.

One thing that was holding them back was materials. Aluminium has been essential for the advancement of aerospace technologies, and until the Hall-Héroult process was discovered in around 1890 it was impossible to make in large quantities (bars of aluminium were included in a display of Napoleon III's crown jewels because it was so expensive to make). Within 20 years of aluminium being industrialised we had the first powered flight (using an engine built from it) and within 80 years we had men on the moon, riding a rocket also built from it.

Materials science would also hold them back from nuclear power.  Even with an understanding of atomic theory, purifying (and enriching!) uranium was not a thing Victorian chemical engineers were up to doing.

Uranium was a known element in the Victorian Era, with the radioactive properties not known until 1896 which is just 5 years before the era ends. A fusion rocket engine would "burn" very light elements like helium, hydrogen, and lithium which were all known in the Victorian Era, not heavy elements like uranium. The differing isotopes would not be discovered until the 1930s but if we assume knowledge of nuclear fusion was sent to Earth in the 1800s by some extraterrestrial source then it would also convey some idea of how nuclear fusion worked, and with it the modern model of the atom.

@MacGuffin Helium was not isolated on Earth until the very end of the Victorian era, and even if they knew of the isotopes, getting a significant amount of helium-3 would have been beyond Victorian industry. It certainly wouldn't qualify as something that can be "easily produced".

Helium-3 is sought for fusion power today because it is a fusion fuel that would produce a minimal amount of neutron radiation.  Neutron radiation is a concern because a neutron has no charge so it cannot be contained by a magnetic field.  If there's no concern on limiting the neutron radiation then that leaves many options open.  Even if neutron radiation is a concern then a  hydrogen-boron reaction could be used, and boron was a known element in the Victorian Era. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aneutronic_fusion#Boron

RTGs were not used on the Apollo system other than to power experiments on the Moon, The modules were powered with batteries and fuel cells.

"transistors were vital to getting radar to work" - Um, no?  1940s radar was all vacuum tubes

@Alex - Well, vacuums tubes were in very limited quantities in the Victorian era too - 0. Though with detailed explanations I'm sure they could have produced them in quantity. The first vacuum diode being invented in 1904 and Queen Victoria died in 1901 - Fleming (an Englishman no less) almost invented it during the Victorian era. Transistors were important to NASA due to weight constraints, but when you're riding an Epstein rocket - not a big deal.

@GaryWalker "ENIAC lost one vacuum tube roughly every day or two. With almost 18000 tubes, locating and replacing the failed one was challenging." These were state of the art vacuum tubes c.a. 1950, not experimental devices from the 1906 (the date of the first triode).

Reliability is going to be a problem even with non-electronic components. With sufficient time and good enough instructions, a Victorian-era artisan might replicate a high-performance bolt or shielding panel, even making special high-performance alloys and other materials if needed, but what is the failure rate going to be without x-ray NDT inspection equipment? You're going to need to be able to consistently produce components that come close to their physically achievable levels of performance.

I see two additional problems: decoding the message, and life support
Decoding the Message
Have you ever tried to assemble a piece of flatpack furniture, following instructions translated from LOTE by a speaker of ESL? Was it not difficult, even though the author was human, with the same sort of eyes and fingers as you have? Now imagine an alien writing instructions in an alien language (Unless you make the assumptions that all highly intelligent life forms are humanoid, and speak English).
Either way, we have the problem of decrypting the message. I expect that 18th century cryptographers hadn't forgotten the techniques used a couple of centuries earlier, but they certainly weren't at the Bletchley Park level, and Bletchley Park was working with a known language. They had a German Enigma machine, that the Poles had captured; they knew the language and the format of the messages they were trying to crack; they had Alan Turing, who had also stood on the shoulders of giants; they had relay logic in their machines, later replaced with vacuum tubes; and they had all the resources that were needed to win not lose the war.
Decryption is just the first step if the message is written in an unknown language: consider the problem with Etruscan, which is, at least, a human language.

The Etruscan alphabet is similar to the Greek one. Therefore, linguists have been able to read the inscriptions in the sense of knowing roughly how they would have been pronounced, but have not yet understood their meaning.

Lack of feedback is also a problem. In my experience the first cut of the user manual for a product needs to be reviewed by users, and substantially revised. Your aliens are presumably experts in their technology, but they don't know much about how 18th century folk would interpret their message.
Life support
As @void_ptr pointed out, it's a bit awkward if our bold astronauts are DOA. You need to consider how you keep the air in, maintain oxygen levels, get rid of CO2, keep the living quarters warm (a roaring coal fire won't cut it).

The chemical compounds and reactions for basic life support systems were known in the Victorian era, and occasionally used for things like rescue operations in deep coal mines where the ventilation had failed. There just wasn't much practical need for them until the submarine became popular.
